Ubuntu Install boots a black screen
I used UNetbootin to install the ISO for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
After rebooting my PC I get this screen.

After clicking enter on UNetbootin it takes me to this screen.

No matter which option I click it will show this line of code:
Booting 'Install Ubuntu'  
(hd0,1)  
Filesystem type is ntfs, partition type 0x7  
[Linux-bzImage, setup=0x4e00, size=0xe37988]  
[Linux-initrd @ 0x7b84e000, 0x47a10cc bytes]  

After a few seconds the font changes for about half a second before it boots into a black screen.

How to I fix this error so that I can continue installing Ubuntu?

What causes this error to occur in the first place?


The computer is very old from 2008, but it has 4GB RAM and an Intel dual core processor.
System specs:


I forgot to mention, I'm trying to dual-boot with windows 7 ultimate edition 32 bit OS

If old Windows 7 system, it probably is too old for Ubuntu. You may need lighter weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)
You cannot install Ubuntu to NTFS partitions, it needs Linux formats like ext4. Use Windows tools to shrink Windows and make unallocated space. Do note Windows 7 is very obsolete and should not be used to connect to Internet.

The computer is very old from 2008.

I fixed it, it was an ID10T error, I was installing to a NTFS partition and I thinksies that Linux uses ext4. So I was installing it wrong. I Changed the filesystem type to ext4 (had to download a app off the Internet in windows 7 bc windows can't format as ext4)
